# Finding the Max and Min of many values in a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to get maximum and minimum values of numerical values for ticket logs

This is over a historical excel sheet and I've been instructed not to edit the order or formatting in any way.

In a new sheet I have created a list of Ticket Type names and time + min and max
In the original sheet (among others) is the Ticket Type name "time to complete" in days (1.1, 2.5, 30.0 etc.)

Due to the nature of the data, I cannot list it here

There are over 100,000 rows, not in a useful order (for me)

```
Sheet 1
Ticket Name      Time to Complete
Ticket Name 2    1.2
Ticket Name 4    5.6
Ticket Name 2    62.6
Ticket Name 16   38.1
.... (x100,000)
```

What I would like in the second sheet is something like this

```
Sheet 2
Ticket Name    Count   Min    Max    Diff    
Ticket Name 1  135     0.2    12.0   11.8    
Ticket Name 26 44      11.8   182.0  170.2
....
Ticket Name 26 22      1.6    6.3    4.7
```

I get the idea of using a VLOOKUP, but that (as far as I'm aware) will only get me the first value - every one in a list of over 1,000, that I can also "click and drag" down for every Ticket Name

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: use a pivot table.

Comment: This is of course excel and a thousend ways will get you to rome, so if you want vlookup because for some reason pivot table does not work for you, do it in a makro where you create columns with vlookup which then copys only the values into new columns and then deletes the vlookup columns. So ppl can look without excel dieing because of too many vlookups but you can still refresh it. You can use the makro recorder for this ;)

Comment: Thank you both. A Pivot wasn't requested, so I never really thought of it - great solution, but the formula should help if I need to live edit data etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count: `=countif(sheet1!A:A, A2)`

For Office 2016 and newer

Min: `=minifs(sheet1!B:B, sheet1!A:A, A2)`

Max: `=maxifs(sheet1!B:B, sheet1!A:A, A2)`

For those older than Office 2016, use `Array Formula`

Min: `=min(if(sheet1!A:A=A2, sheet1!B:B, ""))`, then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>

Max: `=max(if(sheet1!A:A=A2, sheet1!B:B, ""))`, then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

As commented before, you might want to look into a pivot table.

However, if your way to go is using formulas then try this:

1). Put this formula in Sheet2 cell C2:

```
=MIN(IF(Sheet1!A:A=A2,Sheet1!B:B))
```

Confirm with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, and drag your formula down.

2). Put this formula in Sheet2 cell D2:

```
=MAX(IF(Sheet1!A:A=A2,Sheet1!B:B))
```

Confirm with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, and drag your formula down.

Comment: Thank you! Marking the other as answer, just because it has the `minifs`